# Converting Text to DXF with Laser-Compatible Font (e.g., tl_lasersans) using ezdxf Library in Python

Tags: python, text, translation, dxf, ezdxf

I'm working on a Python project where I need to convert text into DXF format, specifically to create laser-readable text for laser cutting applications. I would like to use the font tl_lasersans for this purpose.

I'm currently using the ezdxf library in Python to work with DXF files. However, I'm unsure how to use a specific font like tl_lasersans and ensure that the resulting text is compatible with laser cutting machines.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to convert text to DXF format using the tl_lasersans font or any other laser-compatible font using the ezdxf library? Are there any specific attributes or settings that need to be configured to ensure laser readability?

I appreciate any help or suggestions you can provide. Thank you!

"I have already tried to implement the conversion, but the following issue occurs: while the entered text is output as a DXF file, it is not in a laser-readable font."

Please let me know if there is anything else you would like to discuss or if there are further details you would like to provide. I'm here to assist you.

Comment: You're here to assist me? You're asking me to provide more details?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

- Can you provide what kind of entities are you using in the DXF (TEXT or MTEXT).
- Also show an example of the text you want to convert.

Here is some links to ezdxf docs how to set fonts for text:

- [using Style](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tables/style_table_entry.html)
- [using MTEXT entity](https://ezdxf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/mtext.html)

I know about dxf content, but not laser cutting applications, so not sure about compatibility.

I have a library written in TypeScript that generate dxf [@tarikjabiri/dxf](https://github.com/dxfjs/writer) but ezdxf is better.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).